# ntlmssp_handle_neg_flags: Got challenge flags[0x60898205] - possible downgrade detected! missing_flags[0x00000010] - NT code 0x80090302

Tags: centos, samba, centos7

I'm trying to access SMB/CIFS resource on NetApp, using following and getting error:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
$ rpm -qa | grep ^samba-
samba-client-4.2.10-6.el7_2.x86_64
samba-libs-4.2.10-6.el7_2.x86_64
samba-common-libs-4.2.10-6.el7_2.x86_64
samba-common-4.2.10-6.el7_2.noarch
samba-client-libs-4.2.10-6.el7_2.x86_64
samba-common-tools-4.2.10-6.el7_2.x86_64
$ smbclient //X/Y$ -U DOMAIN/user -L
Enter DOMAIN/user's password: 
ntlmssp_handle_neg_flags: Got challenge flags[0x60898205] - possible downgrade detected! missing_flags[0x00000010] - NT code 0x80090302
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
SPNEGO(ntlmssp) login failed: NT code 0x80090302
session setup failed: NT code 0x80090302
$
```

---

I'm trying to use following with my `smbclient`:

> --option==
>
> ```
> Set the smb.conf(5) option "<name>" to value "<value>" from the command line. This overrides compiled-in defaults and options read from the configuration file.
> ```

yet, I'm still unable to access resource on server as I'm doing it wrong:

```
$ smbclient //X/Y$ -U DOMAIN/user -L --option='client ntlmv2 auth'=no
Enter DOMAIN/user's password: 
Connection to --option=client ntlmv2 auth=no failed (Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)
$
```

What is right way to set `client ntlmv2 auth=no` via `--option` in `smbclient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to disable spnego within ntlmssp, with default params :

`# smbclient -L //MY_SERVER -U MY_USER
Enter MY_USER's password:
ntlmssp_handle_neg_flags: Got challenge flags[0x60898205] - possible downgrade detected! missing_flags[0x00000010] - NT code 0x80090302
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN`

with spnego disabled :

`# smbclient -L //MY_SERVER -U MY_USER --option='client use spnego=no'`

worked for me.

Comment: disabling `spnego` works for me as well (only via `smbclient`) and I still unable to access it via `Places` menu via `GNOME`.